# Attach two different pdfs to email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I receive an order via Google Form. I send an automatic email with the (a) personalised pdf with the order, but I also want to add a (b) pdf to the email coming from a Google Drive folder (terms and services, the same for all orders).

(A) is working fine, but I am not sure how to add (B).

This is the personalised pdf:

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
  sendEmail(e.namedValues['email'][0],pdfFile);
}
function sendEmail(email,pdfFile){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Order received","Please find attached your order and terms of services", {
    attachments: [pdfFile],
    name: 'MyCompany'
  });
}
function createPDF(info) {
const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXX");  
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXX");  
const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("XXXXXXXXX");
const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
const body = openDoc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{fn}", info['First name'][0]);
body.replaceText("{ln}", info['Last name'][0]);
openDoc.saveAndClose();
const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['First name'][0] + " " + info['Last name'][0]);
tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
return pdfFile;
}
```

So I have created `const pdfTerms = DriveApp.getFileById("XXXXXXXXX");`  and I have added it to `attachments: [pdfFile,pdfTerms]` of `sendEmails` however it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

The issue is that `pdfTerms` in your approach is not a `pdf` but an object of type [`file`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file).

To convert the `file` to a `pdf` you need to do that:

```
const pdfTerms_file = DriveApp.getFileById("XXXXXXXXX"); // type of file
const pdfTerms = pdfTerms_file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF); // pdf
```

always assuming that there is a file with this particular id.

### Solution:

Modify `afterFormSubmit` and `sendEmail` as follows:

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
  const pdfTerms_file = DriveApp.getFileById("XXXXXXXXX"); // type of file
  const pdfTerms = pdfTerms_file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF); // pdf
  sendEmail(e.namedValues['email'][0],pdfFile,pdfTerms);
}
function sendEmail(email,pdfFile,pdfTerms){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Order received","Please find attached your order and terms of services", {
    attachments: [pdfFile,pdfTerms],
    name: 'MyCompany'
  });
}
```

**References:**

- [getAs(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getAs(String))